# $G$-invariant divisor in affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, group-actions, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Suppose we have a linearly reductive group $G$ acting on $X=\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ and we have a closed subvariety $Z=V(f_1,...,f_k)$, where $f_i$ are $G$-invariant functions. If we further know that $Z$ is in fact a divisor, $Z=V(f)$ and $(f)=(f_1,...,f_k)$, can we conclude that $f$ itself can be chosen to be $G$-invariant?

I don't even know if it is possible to rule out the case where $f$ is a *relative* $G$-invariant, that is $f(gx)=\chi (g) f(x)$ for all $g \in G, x \in X$ and a character $\chi$ of $G$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the question: are you requiring that the ideal generated by $f$ be *equal* to the ideal generated by $f_1,\dots,f_k$, as in the third line of your question, or are you only asking *Supposing $Z$ is a $G$-stable divisor in affine space, is there a $G$-invariant polynomial with zero set $Z$*?

Comment: Now that I think about that, the latter would be good enough for me, because I am really interested in $\mathcal{O}^*(X-Z)$.

Comment: I suppose you must also assume that there is *some* set of $G$-invariant polynomials with common zero set $Z$.